# Is it possible in Node.js to detect if code executes some other script/file

Tags: node.js

Imagine this code:

```
const myFunc = () => exec('node foo.js')
```

Now my library executes myFunc, but it doesn't know if it executes another script. How to make it know it?

P.S. The lib, which is a test runner + coverage tool, needs to know every piece of code that was run by the test.

Comment: Why does the lib need to 'know' this? This is none of its concern. A function is a function.

Comment: The lib, which is a test runner + coverage tool, needs to know every piece of code that was run by the test. This is a simplified description.

Comment: Consider updating the question with relevant details, so it would be clearer for users who may have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a need to detect API calls that may result in uncontrolled script execution and there's a need to detect calls, APIs have to be patched, e.g.:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const { exec } = childProcess;
childProcess.exec = function () {
  console.error(new Error('No coverage'));
  return exec.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This applies to `global.eval`, `global.Function`, all `child_process` module functions, some `vm` and `worker_threads` functions.

Comment: Wow, I always over-engineer things, when indeed this (patching/decorating) can be done! Great idea, thanks! And listing possible patch-ables is very good!